# Update CSS using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the following Javascript to open and close div blocks for a FAQ style page.
I'm trying to get the LI to display a cursor:pointer only if there is a child div below it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#faqs li').each(function() {
            var tis = $(this),
            state = false,
            answerNext = tis.next('div').hide().css('height','auto').slideUp();
            answerAll = $('#faqs').children('div').hide().css('height','auto').slideUp();
            tis.click(function() {
                state = !state;
                answerAll.slideUp(state);
                $('#faqs').children('li').removeClass('active');
                answerNext.slideToggle(state);
                tis.addClass('active',state);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I add the class for cursor:pointer to the LI only IF the child div exists?

Here is the HTML I'm using:

```
<div id="faqs">
<ul class="servicelist">
<div class="servicelisttitle">List Title</div>
<li>List Item Without Div</li>
<li>List Item WITH Div</li>
<div>This will open when above LI is clicked</div>
<li>List Item Without Div</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you show some sample HTML? You're talking about child `div` elements, but the code is referring to siblings (via `next()`).

Comment: Well if you spell the cursor attribute in your CSS the same as you do here, it's not going to do anything regardless of what we tell you.

Comment: Thanks for that, Charles!  Guess I need one more cup of coffee...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show much code, but if you have something like

```
<ul id="faqs">
    <li>No child</li>
    <li>Child<div>Something</div></li>
    <li>Still no child</li>
    <li>With Child<div>Something else</div></li>
</ul>
```

You can just select all the child divs, then take their parents (the `li`s with `div` children):

```
$('#faqs > li > div').parent().css('cursor','pointer');
```

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wv9c895h/).

Comment: I'm keeping the "SOMETHING" hidden until the "Child" is clicked.

Comment: jQuery can still select the element if it's hidden, so that doesn't matter. It'll still work.

Comment: My HTML has the DIV outside of the LI.  Should your code still work?

Comment: No, the HTML you've updated your question with is invalid. The only allowed children of `ul` elements are `li` elements.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks KBA!  I appreciate the help!  I think I got it going like I wanted it.